# Macro for reading matrix C++

Tags: c++, macros

I'm trying to define macros to read and print matrices in C++, but I'm trying something different, and it's not working:

```
#define rm(A, m, n, type) 
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) 
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
            scanf("%##type##", &A[i][j]);
```

A is the matrix (int or char)

I want to write d or c to read int or char, but this code isn't working and I don't even know why, I just tried to use the concat ## symbol to create the string that scanf receive as argument, but it bugs.

My questions are:

1 - why is it wrong?

2 - how can I make this macro work fine? 
(if necessary, the solution may contain 1 or 2 macro declarations, but short ones, otherwise I wouldn't ask and I could just create a macro for int and other for char.

PS: this macro is written one line, the algorithm above is just to show what it does.

Thanks

Comment: Macros are evil.  Make it an inlined function.  For example, macros allow you to pass "hello" as one parameter and "Frog" as the type.

Comment: BTW, use of curly braces, `{` and `}`, do not affect run-time and have negligible effect on compilation.  Use them.  It's a way to reduce defects.

Comment: I think the issue is substituting within a character literal.  You may have to pass the entire `scanf` format string.

Comment: Don't bother reading the second matrix. The series really went downhill after the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *really must* make a macro for this - which, as others have pointed out, is a Really Bad Idea and Not The Right Way To Do This - the issue that you're encountering is that macros are interpreted by the preprocessor, which treats line breaks as as the end of a macro replacement. To fix this, you'll need to introduce some escape sequences at the ends of the lines:

```
#define rm(A, m, n, type) \
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) \
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) \
            scanf("%" #type, &A[i][j]);
```

Notice that I've factored out your use of the token-pasting operator from the inside of the string, since the preprocessor doesn't fill in string literals for you, and instead opted to use the stringizing operator `#` to convert the type to a string literal. Since the compiler automatically concatenates adjacent string literals together, there's no need to paste anything. I should repeat that *this is a really bad idea* in that it hurts code readability and doesn't offer anything you can't already do with a regular C++ function.

You've tagged this question as C++, though, so I should point out that `scanf` has all sorts of type safety issues that can come up, so it's almost certainly safer to use the `iostream` library, which for all its faults does catch a ton of possible errors at compile-time.

Fundamentally, though, you shouldn't use macros for this. Just write a regular old function. Here's one way to do this, which has the added benefit that it automatically infers the sizes of arrays:

```
template <typename T, size_t m, size_t n>
void readArray(T (&array)[m][n], std::istream& source = std::cin) {
   for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++) {
          source >> array[i][j];
      }
   }
}
```

Now, you can say something like this:

```
double arr[137][42];
readArray(arr);
```

to read an array of `double`s from `cin`, or

```
int arr[5][5];
ifstream input("my-file.txt");
readArray(arr, input);
```

to read an array of `int`s from an external file. This is type-safe and will raise a compiler error if you try reading in a case where the array size isn't defined or where the type can't be read. This prevents all sorts of possible problems. Compare this with your macro, where I could do something like this:

```
int arr[5][5];
rm(arr, 6, 6, f);
```

Oops - I just used the wrong array size and the wrong `scanf` specifier. Any time you can offload work to the compiler that saves you from having to make code changes across lots of places, it's worth considering!